# Sequential Observable Web Service and Database Query Call

Tags: rx-java, observable

How to implement a sequential web service and database query call using RxJava Observable? First call is the database query (cache) then display the result (onNext or onCompleted) and after that is the network call then display (replace) the current result (cache). I'm using Volley with listener to display the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sequential actions can be implemented using `concat`. Because two concatenated Observables can be of different types `ignoreElements` and `cast` can be useful:

```
databaseQueryObservable
    .doOnNext(displayResult)
    .doOnComplete(something)
    .ignoreElements()
    .cast(Object.class)
    .concatWith(
        networkCall
            .doOnNext(displayNetworkCallResult)
            .doOnComplete(somethingElse)
            .ignoreElements()
            .cast(Object.class)
    ).subscribe(onNextAction, onErrorAction, onCompletedAction);
```

Comment: Do I need subscriber onCompleted inside databaseQueryObservable and NetworkCall? Can you give me an example? Also the subscriber implementation. Thank you.

Comment: totally up to you. I'll insert extra calls for you to do stuff as you please. In terms of the subscriber you could also do new Subscriber<Object>{} and implement the required methods as you please (perhaps just for logging?).